# Custom configuration files or localization files, maybe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an idiom that I should be using for custom configuration data? In this case, I want to include some YAML data that describes some strings on my site. Is there a built in way to do this, or should I use my own YAML file? If I should use my own YAML files is there any infrastructure built out for supporting this (obviously besides YAML.load_file)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your own file to `config/locales` :

```
# my_config_data.en.yml
en:
  my_config_data:
    some_symbol: "Foo"
    "some_string": "Bar"
    # ...
```

Then you can access your configs with the `I18N.t` method:

```
I18n.t(:'my_config_data.some_symbol') # => "Foo"
I18n.t('my_config_data.some_string')  # => "Bar"
```

That is good for strings. If there are more data types in your config, you can use one of these plugins:

- http://github.com/Oshuma/app_config
- http://github.com/bowsersenior/behavior